# Conditional dependency between beans in Spring Context

Tags: spring

In my Spring application context I have `DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean` which is always required in application context as it is responsible for dynamic bean definitions for data sources and hibernate session factories for all the databases (identical schema, multiple databases) registered in the system. There is another bean `LiquibaseInitBean` which is only present when profile **development** is active, and is responsible for applying [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/index.html) database upgrades on each database registered in the system.

It would be nice to make `DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean` to depend on `LiquibaseInitBean` (**whenever** it is present, meaning development profile is active) so that `DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean` always sees up-to-date database schema.

```
<beans>

    <!-- other beans.... -->

    <bean id="dynamicSessionFactoryInitBean" class="my.app.DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean"  />

    <beans profile="development">
        <bean id="liquibaseInitBean" class="my.app.liquibase.LiquibaseInitBean" />
    </beans>
<beans>
```

Simply adding `depends-on="liquibaseInitBean"` attribute for `DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean` definition will obviously cause problems (No bean named 'LiquibaseInitBean' is defined) when development profile is not active. Is there a "conditional depends on" or "depends on if present" type facility in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Define your dynamicSessionFactoryInitBean in two profiles the default and developement profiles. Make dynamicSessionFactoryInitBean dependent on liquibaseInitBean only in the development profile as follows

```
<beans>
   <!-- other beans.... -->
   <beans profile="default">
      <bean id="dynamicSessionFactoryInitBean" class="my.app.DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean"  />
   </beans>

   <beans profile="development">
      <bean id="liquibaseInitBean" class="my.app.liquibase.LiquibaseInitBean" />
      <bean id="dynamicSessionFactoryInitBean" class="my.app.DynamicSessionFactoryInitBean" depends-on="liquibaseInitBean" />
   </beans>
<beans>
```

NB. The default profile is always activated when no other profile has been activated

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out.